# Inequality of Sup and Integral of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Suppose $f': [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ exists and is continuous. Suppose also then $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in [0,1]$, prove $$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq \left( \int_{[0,1]} |f'(x)|^2 \, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

I'm not really sure about this one. I tried to use the fact that $f(x) < f'(t)$ for each $x \in [0,1]$ and some $t \in [0,1]$ by MVT and the fact that $f(c) = 0$ for some $c$, and apply the Schwarz inequality somehow, though I don't know how to proceed.

A **hint** would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to prove the inequality is saturated by the linear functions $f(x)=c x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this inequality is true? Since the condition on $f$ remains valid when we scale $f$, for any $\alpha$ we should have

$$ |\alpha| \|f\|_{\infty} = \| \alpha f \|_{\infty} \leq \| \alpha f' \|_2^2 = \alpha^2 \|f'\|_2^2 $$

whenever $f$ satisfies the given condition. Now dividing both sides by $\alpha$ and letting $\alpha \to 0$, we should have

$$ \| f\|_{\infty} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f \equiv 0.$$

This is clearly absurd. So I guess that the exponet $\tfrac{1}{2}$ is missing on the RHS. Then the inequality follows from the FToC and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

---

**EDITED.** Hint for the edited question: Notice the following inequality

$$ |f(x)| = |f(x) - f(c)| = \left|\int_{c}^{x} f'(t) \, dt\right| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f'(t)| \, dt. $$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Could you elaborate just a bit on using ftoc? This was one of the first things I tried, but I didn't see how to write it in a useful form.

Comment: Yes aha, in fact I finished right before your edit. Regardless, thank you for your time.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Glad you finished it by yourself :)